# how to converting a for loop with await into asyncio.gather()

Tags: python

how do I write the following piece of code using asyncio.gather and map?

```
        for i in range(len(data)):
            candlestick = data[i]
            candlesticks = data[0: i + 1]
            await strategy.execute(candlesticks, candlestick.startTime)
```

Comment: Read this document, maybe help
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
from asyncio import gather, create_task
tasks = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    candlestick = data[i]
    candlesticks = data[0: i + 1]
    tasks.append(create_task(strategy.execute(candlesticks, candlestick.startTime)))
results = await gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `map()` specifically, you could do this:

```py
from asyncio import gather, create_task

await gather(
    *map(
        lambda i: create_task(
            strategy.execute(data[0: i + 1], data[i].startTime)
        ),
        range(len(data))
)
```